# A vector of objects is not being populated

Tags: c++, object, vector

I've created multiple classes and each on them hold a vector of objects.
Essentially, when I try to add the `vector<Controller>` to the StorageConnection object it shows that storageConnection object does not have any controller values in it. I've made sure to print out the elements in `vector<Controller>` before adding it to the StorageConnection object, so I know that `vector<Controller>` is populated.

For some reason when I try to copy the content from `controllerListTemp` to  `storageConnectionTemp.getFileSystem(0)`, `storageConnectionTemp.getFileSystem(0).getControllerSize()` always returns a size of 0.

NOTE: Sadly I am using C++98 on this current project, so I may be limited to newer c++ features

```
class Host
{
public: 
    Host () : hostName_("") { }
    // setters and getters for hostName_
private:
    string hostName_;
};

class Controller
{
public: 
    Controller() : controllerName_(""), hostList_() { }
    int getHostListSize() {...}
    Host getHost( int index ) { return hostList_.at(index); }
    Host getHost( string hostName ) {...}
    vector<Host> getHostList() { return hostList_;}
    void addToHostList(Host host) { hostList_.push_back(host); }
    void clearHostList() { hostList_.clear(); }
    // setters and getters for controllerName_
private:
    string controllerName_;
    vector<Host> hostList_;
};

class FileSystem
{
public: 
    FileSystem() : fileSystemName_(""), ControllerList_() { }
    int getControllerListSize() {...}
    Host getController( int index ) { return controllerList_.at(index); }
    Host getController( string controllerName ) {...}
    vector<Controller> getControllerList() { return controllerList_;}
    void addToControllerList(Controller controller) { controllerList_.push_back(controller); }
    void clearControllerList() { controllerList_.clear(); }

    // setters and getters for fileSystemName_
private:
    string fileSystemName_;
    vector<Controller> controllerList_;
};

class StorageConnection
{
public: 
    StorageConnection() : siteName_(""), FileSystemList_() { }

    int getFileSystemListSize() {...}
    Host getFileSystem ( int index ) { return fileSystemList_.at(index); }
    Host getFileSystem ( string fileSystemName) {...}
    vector<FileSystem > getFileSystem List() { return fileSystemList_;}
    void addToFileSystemList(FileSystem fileSystem) { fileSystemList_.push_back(fileSystem); }
    void clearFileSystemList() { fileSystemList_.clear(); }

    // setters and getters for siteName_
private:
    string siteName_;
    vector<FileSystem> fileSystemList_;
};
```

Lets assume that the method `populateStorageConnection()` has access to all the classes from above.

```
void populateStorageConnection()
{
    vector<Controller> controllerListTemp; 
    StorageConnection storageConnectionTemp;
    
 // already populated the controllerListTemp vector and the fileSystemList member in storageConnectionTemp
// add the controllerList to the storageConnectionTemp object
    for ( int controllerCounter = 0; i < controllerListTemp_.size(); controllerCounter++ )
    {
       storageConnectionTemp.getFileSystem(0).addControllerList(controllerListTemp.at(controllerCounter));
       
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, there is no need for a user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator in `Controller`, `Host`, `FileSystem`, `StorageConnection` classes.  Why did you write these functions?  All of the member variables of all of these classes are safely copyable and assignable as-is.  By writing your own versions of the assignment op and copy constructor, you are inviting bugs to occur, plus the code is less-optimal than it should be due to you thwarting what the compiler default version of the copy / assignment functions will do.

Comment: [Your code without the fixes required, but with the unnecessary functions removed](https://godbolt.org/z/ebvbYrYzq).

Comment: "I am using C++98 on this current project" Why just not walk away? Is there shortage of non-sadistic employers in your area?

Answer (score 3):

```
Host getFileSystem ( int index ) { return fileSystemList_.at(index); }
```

This class method returns a `Host` from the `fileSystemList` vector.

The returned `Host` object has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the original `Host` object that exists in the `fileSystemList`. It's still there. Nothing happened to it. Nothing will happened to it no matter what subsequently happens to the object that you got from `getFileSystem`.

This is because `getFileSystem` returns ***a copy*** of the object in the vector. This is how objects work, in C++, when they get passed or returned from functions ***by value***.

> For some reason when I try to copy the content from controllerListTemp to
> storageConnectionTemp.getFileSystem(0), storageConnectionTemp.getFileSystem(0).getControllerSize() always returns a size of 0.

Of course. `getFilesystem(0)` returns a `Host` object. You can do whatever you want with it afterwards, but it will have absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the original `Host` that `getFileSystem(0)` ***makes a copy of*** and returns.

You are expecting objects to work in C++ like they do in Java, C#, Perl, Python, or other languages. C++ is not Java, C#, Perl, Python, or other languages. C++ works in fundamentally different ways.

If you look at your textbook's description of a vector's `at()` method -- the very same one that the above `getFileSystem()` uses -- you will see that your textbook describes that `at()` returns the value in the vector ***by reference*** instead of ***by value***.

Perhaps your intent is for `getFileSystem()` to return a ***reference to a `Host`***, a `Host &`. Then, referencing the returned object ends up referencing the original object in the vector (after making the requisite changes to `getFileSystem()`):

```
Host &h=storageConnectionTemp.getFileSystem(0);
```

Then, making modification to `h` ends up modifying the actual `Host` object in `storageConnectionTemp`'s vector.

And you also need to fully understand the rules for references and vectors. If the underlying vector's size changes and it causes reallocation, all references to the objects in the vector will be invalidated, and all further usage of them results in your undefined behavior.

See your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but the tone seems unnecessarily harsh and judgemental. (I admit I've been similarly unfriendly on occasion, although I usually limit them to comments, not answers.)